# Is it Possible to Share JavaScript Vendor Dependencies Between Two Separate Apps Using Laravel-Mix + Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I am still relatively new to Laravel Mix and modular JavaScript, so please excuse me if I use the wrong terminology in this question.

I have a Core application that I would like to write plugins for.  I would like the plugins to inherit (or share) 3rd party libraries in the Core app's extracted vendor.js file. My goal is to reuse dependencies without having to generate a redundant vendor.js file with some of the same libraries all over again.

I'm having difficulty getting the plugin JavaScript code to access libraries that exist in the Core app.

To better illustrate what I am talking about, I created a super simple HTML app with no server-side logic to simulate a Core app and a plugin app called "myPlugin". I would like MyPlugin to use Javascript dependencies contained in Core's vendor.js file.

The directory structure looks like this, and I created a [public Git Repo with the full example](https://github.com/homestar9/plugin-test/tree/d52f38627e6df9f6df1b934ecceaa89c7d524d8e):

[image: Directory Structure for Example]

The Core app has a View (/core/index.html), which depends on jQuery and a jQuery plugin called Typewatch. Both dependencies have been extracted to a vendor.js file.

The Plugin app has a View (/myPLugin/index.html), which shares the same Core layout but adds a second search box that also depends on JQuery and Typewatch.

Both the Core and MyPlugin folders have their own webpack.mix.js files.

**Core app:**

The /core/webpack.mix.js file looks like this:

```
let mix = require( 'laravel-mix' );

mix.autoload( {
    jquery: [ '$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery' ]
} );

mix.setPublicPath( 'dist' );

// vendor extraction
mix.extract( [ 
    'jquery',
    'jquery.typewatch'
] );

mix
    .js( 'src/app.js', 'dist' ) // universal app file for all entrypoints
    .js( 'src/index.js', 'dist' ) // specific entrypoint js file
;
```

The /core/index.html looks like this:

```
// ... HTML boilerplate
<h1>Core app</h1>
        
<form>
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
</form>

<!-- View gets rendered here -->
<div id="view"></div>

<!-- core scripts -->
<script src="./dist/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/app.js"></script>

<!-- entrypoint specific script -->
<script src="./dist/index.js"></script>
// ... HTML boilerplate
```

The /core/src/app.js universal script file looks like this:

```
require( "jquery.typewatch" );

// init the search field with typewatch
const searchField = $( '#search' ).typeWatch( {
    callback: function( value ) {
        console.log( 'you typed ' + value );
    },
    wait: 0,
    highlight: true,
    captureLength: 2
} );
```

**Plugin Files:**

The /myPlugin/webpack.mix.js file looks like this:

```
let mix = require( 'laravel-mix' );

mix.setPublicPath( 'dist' );

// vendor extraction
mix.extract( [] );

mix.js( 'src/index.js', 'dist' ); // specific entrypoint js file
```

The /myPlugin/index.html file looks like this:

```
// ... HTML boilerplate
<h1>Core app</h1>
        
<form>
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
</form>

<!-- View gets rendered here -->
<div id="view"></div>

<!-- myplugin adds a second search box -->
<form>
    <input type="search" name="pluginSearch" id="pluginSearch" placeholder="Plugin Search" />
</form>

<!-- core scripts -->
<script src="../core/dist/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="../core/dist/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="../core/dist/app.js"></script>

<!-- plugin specific scripts -->
<script src="./dist/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/index.js"></script>
// ... HTML boilerplate
```

The /myPlugin/src/index.js file looks like this:

```
( function() {

    $( '#view' ).text( 'You are looking at myplugin!' );
    
    // init the search field with typewatch
    const searchField = $( '#pluginSearch' ).typeWatch( {
        callback: function( value ) {
            console.log( 'you typed ' + value );
        },
        wait: 0,
        highlight: true,
        captureLength: 2
    } );

} )();
```

**The problem:**

When I load /myPlugin/index.html in a browser, I get an error telling me that jQuery wasn't found.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

How do I allow myPlugin app to share and access dependencies from the Core app's vendor.js file? (see update below)

**Update 9/22/2023**

If I make all vendor dependencies global in the Core app's app.js file AND add the dependency to the list of Webpack externals, it appears to work. ([See this commit in Github](https://github.com/homestar9/plugin-test/commit/9c46a2a18ed7270e1e98dc62ab132144af4eec19))

```
// app.js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require( 'jquery' ); // <-- Make jquery global
require( "jquery.typewatch" ); // <-- this adds functionality to the now global $ object.

//... rest of file unchanged
```

```
// Myplugin webpack.mix.js
let mix = require( 'laravel-mix' );

mix.setPublicPath( 'dist' );

// global dependencies should be marked as external
// this prevents them from being bundled with the plugin
mix.webpackConfig({
    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
});

// ... rest of file unchanged
```

**Further exploration**

I wanted to see how things would work with another dependency, so I added Datatables.net to the mix (pun intended).

To get this to work, I installed Datatables.net to the Core app and added this to the app.js file:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require( 'jquery' ); // <-- Make jquery global
require( "jquery.typewatch" );

import DataTable from 'datatables.net'; // <-- Import datatables.net
window.DataTable = DataTable; // <-- Make datatables.net global

// ... rest of file
```

Just like that, I could use `DataTable` in my plugin. ([See this commit in Github](https://github.com/homestar9/plugin-test/commit/343c3f8f497b37bce0c89e9c993da7b2e70a7ffd))

This solution feels like a code smell. Making all dependencies global just so the Plugin app can use it moves me further away from modular Javascript.

I can't help but wonder if there's a way to continue thinking modularly, and somehow import the dependencies I need directly from the Core's vendor.js file.  Therefore, I am left with the following question:

**Is there a way to use dependencies from a core app without making everything global or redundantly adding them to a separate vendor.js file?**